# Database connect SQLSRV

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I'm trying to connect codeigniter to sql server 2008. My PHP version `PHP Version 5.6.14`.

I get this error. In `PHP_ERROR_LOG`

```
[04-May-2016 04:19:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_sqlsrv: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525
PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

[04-May-2016 04:19:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: sqlsrv: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525
PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

[04-May-2016 04:19:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_sqlsrv: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525
PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

[04-May-2016 04:19:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: sqlsrv: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525
PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

I copy this `php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll` & `php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll` to ext folder.

Any help would be appreciate

Comment: what are your codinator version used in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to use both files, the one with ts at the end means thread safe, which you could use. Also you'll need to add the following line to your php.ini file:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

Cheers!